# Use data from another component in controller

Tags: angular

Using Angular 5, I am creating a form where users select items from one component and want to pass the selected item to another component that filters the web request based on the selection.

For the selection component I am using:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  .....
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit{
  docs;
  selectedqr;

  constructor(public http: HttpClient) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.http.get("https://test.com/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Document Separator Barcodes')/items?$orderBy=ID").subscribe(data => {
      this.docs = data['value'];
    });
  }

  select(ID){
    this.selectedqr = ID;
    console.log(this.selectedqr); //logs correctly
  }

}
```

For the filter component:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { QRCodeModule } from 'angularx-qrcode';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-print',
  .....
})
export class PrintComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() qrcode;
  barcodeitems;

  constructor(public http: HttpClient){

  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.http.get("https://test.com/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Document Separator Barcodes')/items?$orderBy=ID&$filter=ID eq '"+ qrcode +"'").subscribe(data => {
      this.barcodeitems = data['value'];
    });
  }

}
```

How can I use `@Input() qrcode` as a parameter in the web request? Right now I'm getting the error `Cannot find name 'qrcode'. Did you mean the instance member 'this.qrcode'?`

Comment: you can try event emitter.

Comment: i suggest you to create a service for user

Comment: It clearly saying in error message to use 'this' keyworkd, call  'this.qrcode'

Answer (score 0):

I'm the author of [angularx-qrcode](https://github.com/Cordobo/angularx-qrcode) mentioned above. Sorry, I'm little bit late with my answer but it might help others with the same issue.

For those coming here and using the angularx-qrcode-package, I prepared a working angular-app for angular5/6 for you to clone:

https://github.com/Cordobo/angularx-qrcode-sample-app

master-branch: latest angular, at the time of posting angular6
angular5-branch: you guessed it, is for angular5

There is no design (and so it's super-ugly) but you might find the code helpful.